# How can I find and replace values between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, text

I have a dataframe from tidytext that contains the individual words from some survey free-response comments.  It has just shy of 500,000 rows.  Being free-response data, it is riddled with typos.  Using textclean::replace_misspellings took care of almost 13,000 misspelled words, but there were still ~700 unique misspellings that I manually identified.

I now have a second table with two columns, the first is the misspelling and the second is the correction.

For instance

```
allComments <- data.frame("Number" = 1:5, "Word" = c("organization","orginization", "oragnization", "help", "hlp"))
misspellings <- data.frame("Wrong" = c("orginization", "oragnization", "hlp"), "Right" = c("organization", "organization", "help"))
```

How can I replace all the values of `allComments$word` that match `misspellings$wrong` with `misspellings$right`?

I feel like this is probably pretty basic and my R ignorance is showing....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `match` to find the index for words from `allComments$Word` in `misspellings$Wrong` and then use this index to subset them.

```
tt <- match(allComments$Word, misspellings$Wrong)
allComments$Word[!is.na(tt)]  <- misspellings$Right[tt[!is.na(tt)]]
allComments
#  Number         Word
#1      1 organization
#2      2 organization
#3      3 organization
#4      4         help
#5      5         help
```

In case the right word is not already in `allComments$Word` cast it to a `character`:

```
allComments$Word <- as.character(allComments$Word)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another base R solution using `replace()`

```
allComments <- within(allComments, 
                      Word <- replace(Word,
                                      which(!is.na(match(Word,misspellings$Wrong))),
                                      na.omit(misspellings$Right[match(Word,misspellings$Wrong)])))
```

such that

```
> allComments
  Number         Word
1      1 organization
2      2 organization
3      3 organization
4      4         help
5      5         help
```

Answer (score 2):

```
allComments %>%
  left_join(misspellings, by = c("Word" = "Wrong")) %>%
  mutate(Word = coalesce(as.character(Right), Word))
#   Number         Word        Right
# 1      1 organization         <NA>
# 2      2 organization organization
# 3      3 organization organization
# 4      4         help         <NA>
# 5      5         help         help
```

You can, of course, drop the `Right` column when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(allComments)
setDT(misspellings)
df <- merge.data.table(allComments, misspellings, all.x = T, by.x = "Word", by.y = "Wrong")
df <- df[!(is.na(Right)), Word := Right]
df <- df[, c("Number", "Word")]
df <- df[order(Number)]
df

#    Number         Word
#1:      1  organization
#2:      2  organization
#3:      3  organization
#4:      4          help
#5:      5          help
```